# String comparison in Java?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a simple login activity using email and password from my Mysql Database.

Now, i set the email value to "e" and the password to "e1" (to test it).
And i import it to my app into a string, i check if the password and the email are true:

```
res = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email = '"+emailVar+"' AND Password = '"+pswdVar+"' ");
         while (res.next()) {
              String pswdDb = res.getString("Password");
              String emailDb = res.getString("Email");
              if (emailVar == emailDb && pswdVar == pswdDb)
              {

                  Intent I = new Intent (this, MainActivity.class);
                  startActivity(I);
              }
```

but the if statement always returns false.

After debugging i saw that the value from the database and the input value are equal.

How do i fix this??

Comment: Don't compare Strings using `==`. Use the `.equals(..)` method.

Your if-statement then becomes `if (emailVar.equals(emailDb) && pswdVar.equals(pswdDb))`

Comment: are you getting the values from the db ? did you check in logcat which  if the values are equal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings in Java are compared using equals method and not with == operator.

```
    if (emailVar.equals(emailDb) && pswdVar.equals(pswdDb)){

              Intent I = new Intent (this, MainActivity.class);
              startActivity(I);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java and Android `==` is used to compare two objects. To compare two variable you need to use .equals() method as follows,

```
if (emailVar.equals(emailDb) && pswdVar.equals(pswdDb))
{
     Intent I = new Intent (this, MainActivity.class);
     startActivity(I);
}
```